# Read text file in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I wrote some VBA code to write data from a text file. 
In the file I have this text:

```
H|3434|0104-00000107844/18|Peter|Smith|
D|345345345|"III"|
```

`|` character is a delimiter for separating columns in the table.

```vb
Private Sub Polecenie8_Click()

    Dim fieldname As String
    fieldname = "d:\odebrane\tekst1.txt"
    Dim strLineInput As String
    Dim tekst As String
    Dim strLineArray As Variant
    Dim FileNum As Integer

    FileNum = FreeFile()

    Open fieldname For Input As #FileNum

    Do While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, strLineInput

        strLineArray = Split(strLineInput, "|")
        tekst = strLineArray(3)

    Loop
    Me.Tekst0 = tekst

    Close #FileNum

End Sub
```

`strLineArray(0)` is equal D  not H and I don't know why.
I want to save this array in a table, so I want  `strLineArray(0)`  to be equal to H and `strLineArray(5)` to be equal to  D.

Comment: Is the input specification one or two lines? It seems as if you wrote it as two lines, but following the formatting rules, it'll be one line. If it is meant to be two lines, put double spaces before the line break.

Comment: Your code loops over every line in the text file, but if you are only keeping the last value, that's the reason why you get a "D" instead of an "F".

Comment: It looks like you're manually writing to a table from a text file - I'd recommend importing the data once, saving the spec, and then using docmd.transferText to import it in one line of vba

Comment: I text file I will have one or many lines but I can't change formatting of this file becaus I get this file from other aplication.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
Sub imptxttable()
Dim DB As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Dim strSQL As String

Dim strfilepath As String


strfilepath = "your_file.txt"

strSQL = "Select * FROM " & strfilepath

Set DB = OpenDatabase("c:\test", False, False, "Text; Format=Delimited(|);HDR=Yes;CharacterSet=437")
Set rst = DB.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
Debug.Print rst.Fields(0).Name, rst.Fields(0)
With rst
    .MoveLast
    Debug.Print .RecordCount
    .MoveFirst
    For Each fld In rst.Fields
        Debug.Print fld.Name
    Next

End With

rst.Close
DB.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set DB = Nothing
End Sub
```